# Why is this slower?

Tags: python, performance

I have a piece of python code I attempted to optimize, but in doing so, it actually slowed down by a factor of 4. I have no idea why.

```
def q_iteration(self, n:int):
    """Runs q_iteration on the state grid. raw_grid will not be affected"""
    for i in range(n):
        # Create structure to edit without affecting old data
        new_grid = copy.deepcopy(self.state_grid)
        for r in range(len(self.raw_grid)):
            for c in range(len(self.raw_grid[r])):
                new_grid[r][c].update_v(r, c, self.state_grid)


        self.state_grid = new_grid
```

`update_v` is a heavy operation and the speed of the program is becoming very problematic. I decided that in addition to optimizing `update_v`, I changed the references around so that I wasn't creating a new deep copy every iteration.

```
def q_iteration(self, n:int):
    """Runs q_iteration on the state grid. raw_grid will not be affected. Resets any previous iteration"""
    # create copy to edit
    nxt = copy.deepcopy(self.state_grid)
    # create copy to reference data
    curr = self.state_grid

    # clear the current data
    for r in range(len(nxt)):
        for c in range(len(curr)):
            curr[r][c].v = 0

    # update v values
    for i in range(n):
        for r in range(len(self.raw_grid)):
            for c in range(len(self.raw_grid[r])):
                nxt[r][c].update_v(r, c, curr)
        # swap references to overwrite current next iteration
        curr, nxt = nxt, curr

    # set the reference back into the data
    self.state_grid = curr
```

What doesn't make any sense to me is why not creating a deep copy is actually *slower*? Can someone explain this?

Edit: here's update_v

https://pastebin.com/cS2T8Z5t

Comment: @roganjosh: No, `deepcopy` is pure Python and painfully slow (and also kind of buggy).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense but I'm totally wrong, apparently and I won't argue it with 2357112

Comment: Option 1 is optimized for CPU at the expense of memory. Option 2 is optimized for Memory at the expense of CPU

Comment: What's up with the loop to zero out the `v` values in `curr`? Nothing like that happens in the first version.

Comment: @user2357112 it doesn't reuse the object in option 1. They're already 0

Comment: @EthanZ: In option 1, `new_grid` and `self.state_grid` should initially have whatever `v` values `self.state_grid` had going into the method, because `new_grid` is a copy and `self.state_grid` isn't zero'd.

Comment: @user2357112 in option 1, they are all 0s going in. in 2, there's no guarantee of that. However, i thought this was negligible compared to the load of update_v

Comment: I'd suggest collecting some profiling data with cProfile. It can be enlightening :)

Comment: @BenjáminBudai tried that, but it's grabbing the wrong thread.

Comment: @EthanZ Profiling only profiles the current thread. So if you want to profile a specific thread, then you need to start the profiling within that thread. Also, the use of threads in Python in a CPU intensive task doesn't bode well. Two or more threads competing for the CPU will degrade the performance of Python more than if the threads had just run serially.